# ansible crop a substring with jinja2

Tags: regex, replace, ansible, jinja2

I want to crop a sting in ansible, preferably with the replace command.
"db-FFREG.domain.inet" should be changed to "db-FFREG". I already found a solution with split, that is working. But I want to do this with regex

The solution working, but its not so elegant:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    hostname: db-FFREG.domain.inet

  tasks:
    - name: Change hostname into ORACLE SID
      set_fact:
        myOracleSid: "{{hostname.split('.') }}"

    - debug:
        msg:
          -  "ORACLE_SID: {{ myOracleSid[0] }}"
```

The solution which I´d prefer is with jinja2 - no error message, but doesn´t crop anything:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    hostname: db-FFREG.domain.inet

  tasks:
    - name: Change hostname into ORACLE SID
      set_fact:
        myOracleSid: "{{hostname  |  replace('^(.+).domain.inet$','') }}"

    - debug:
        msg:
          -  "ORACLE_SID: {{ myOracleSid }}"
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

well, this one worked!
It is easier, than I thought!

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    hostname: db-FFREG.domain.inet

  tasks:
    - name: Change hostname into ORACLE SID
      set_fact:
        myOracleSid: "{{hostname  |  replace('.domain.inet','') }}"

    - debug:
        msg:
          -  "ORACLE_SID: {{ myOracleSid }}"
```

Comment: Please check my answer, is that what you expected to get?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to remove `.domain.inet` from the *end* of the string, you need to use a regex:

```
{{ hostname | regex_replace('\.domain\.inet$', '') }}
```

Note the `regex_replace` function is used, the dots are escaped to match literal dots and the `$` is used to match the end of string.

To remove all after the first dot, use

```
{{ hostname | regex_replace('\..*', '') }}
```

where `\.`  matches a literal `.` and `.*` matches any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible.